# Grant Offline Access Account Chooser Not Respecting Hosted Domain

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Should the hosted_domain option work like it does with the signIn method?

I am working on integrating Google Sign-In with a project and need to use the server-side workflow. When I pass my organization's domain to the hosted_domain option with signIn it automatically chooses the proper account from the account selector screen for me. When I try to call grantOfflineAccess it presents all accounts to me including my personal accounts with a .gmail domain.

I also tried signing in the user through signIn(), then taking the user object that's returned out of that promise and calling grantOffLineAccess() as appears to be valid in the [Google Developer's Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) thinking that may automatically choose the account for me, but this doesn't work either giving me "Uncaught TypeError: user.grantOfflineAccess is not a function".

I've included the relevant snippet of code from the tutorial guide below.

```html
<!-- Add where you want your sign-in button to render -->
<!-- Use an image that follows the branding guidelines in a real app -->
<button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
<script>
  $('#signinButton').click(function() {
    // signInCallback defined in step 6.
    auth2.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(signInCallback);
  });
</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @Rudolf, you just need to set the authuser param as part of your request

```
var auth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
var user = auth.currentUser.get();
auth.grantOfflineAccess({
    authuser: user.getAuthResponse().session_state.extraQueryParams.authuser
});
```

The orginal answer can be found at  [GoogleUser object does not have grantOfflineAccess method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848870/googleuser-object-does-not-have-grantofflineaccess-method)